# Even numbers from an array (C)

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I can't figured it out why this code does not work properly.
The whole idea was to enter few numbers and output amount of even numbers.

```
    int n, p;

    printf("How many numbers would you like to enter?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int array[n];

    printf("Enter your numbers\n");

    for (int i = 0; i == n; i++) {
        scanf("%d\n", &array[i]);
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
            p++;
        }
    }

    printf("Amount of even numbers: %d", p);
```

Comment: When `i` is 0, it won't equal `n` unless `n` is 0, so the loop will never run. The correct condition is `i < n`.

Comment: Why do you need the array? Your code just discards it and only uses the count anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code fragment:

- `p` is uninitialized: the behavior is undefined. You must initialize `p` as `int p = 0;`
- `scanf("%d\n", &array[i]);` will consume any trailing white space, forcing the user to type the next value before returning. Just use `scanf("%d", &array[i]);`
- the loop test is incorrect: `i == n` is false at the first iteration unless `n` is `0`. You should write:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {...
  ```

Note that you do not need to store the input values into an array but you should check the return value of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behaviour on invalid  input:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, val, p = 0;

    printf("How many numbers would you like to enter? ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter your numbers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &val) != 1) {
            printf("invalid input\n");
            break;
        }
        if (val % 2 == 0) {
            p++;
        }
    }

    printf("Amount of even numbers: %d\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues:

1. You haven't given an initial value for the variable `p`. Many programming language may give it a default value of 0 by default, by that's not the case with C/C++. In C/C++, the default value for a variable is simply a garbage value. What you're doing is incrementing a garbage value instead of incrementing a zero.
2. Your loop condition is wrong. You should loop while `i < n`, not `i == n`.

If you fixed these 2 points, your code will work. But wait! that doesn't mean the code is good. There are still potential issues:

1. **NEVER** create an array of unknown size on the stack. You don't know how large number the user may enter. Your program will crash, which is bad.
2. You're not using the array anyways. You can just take the number and increment your counter.

Answer (score 0):

C is an unsafe language. Unlike many other languages, it does not do anything for you unless you tell it to. I the line:

```
int n,p
```

You create two variables, this tell the compiler to create space for them on the stack. What is does not tell the compiler is what to put into those variables. What ends up happening is whatever was in those memory locations at the time end up in the variables. This can be literally anything and in C terminology is undefined behaviour. (In C undefined is the same as very bad).

What you need to do to fix things is to use:

```
int n = 0;
int p = 0;
```

You can save the work of initializing n since `scanf` does it for you but until you are sure it is a good idea, always initialize variables.

As an aside, be careful with `scanf` you case is fine but when dealing with strings, `scanf` might overflow your variable. To be safe use `sscanf`. This allows you to specify your size.

Comment: There is no need to initialize `n` IMO, the user will enter a value for it anyways.